# Add scroll animation to list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a list where if you click prev next it goes left and right as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/fJqKV/1/)

**HTML**

```
    <div>
    <span id="prev">prev</span>
        <ul id="scrolllist">
            <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff"></li>
            <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/f33636/fff"></li>
            <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0c5b9e/fff"></li>
            <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0c9e0c/fff"></li>
        </ul>
    <span id="next">next</span>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    div {
        float: left;
        width: 550px;
    }
    li {
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
    #prev {
        cursor: pointer;
        float: left;
    }
    #next {
        cursor: pointer;
        float: right;
    }
```

**JS**

```
    $(function () {
        $('#prev').click(function () {
            var first = $('#scrolllist li:first-child');
            $('#scrolllist li').parent().append(first).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
        });
        $('#next').click(function () {
            var last = $('#scrolllist li:last');
            $('#scrolllist li').parent().prepend(last).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
        });
    });
```

This works moves them across as expected however I want to scroll the list items across to get the affect of them going in the clicked direction similar to what can be seen in http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/58/

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Your moving by appending. There is no animating as nothing is moving. Your appending or prepending.

Comment: Sorry your gonna have to go back to the drawing board... You also cant move object unless they have a position.

Comment: If you want a example of how to animate, I have this cascading horizontal slider I built that may help you understand instantiation. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/LCDXj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to doing it right is to place the images in a hidden container div and then animate that container to the left or right as needed, cloning the first or last img in the list and then appending or prepending depending on the direction.

The img container div must be placed inside another div with an explicit height and width with overflow set to hidden.  This prevents the wide img container from being visible to the user.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
<span id="prev">prev</span>
<div class="scroll-container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/f33636/fff">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0c5b9e/fff">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0c9e0c/fff">
    </div>
</div>
<span id="next">next</span>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
$('#prev').click(function () {
    if(!$('.img-container').is(':animated')) {
        var first = $('.img-container img:first-child');
        var firstClone = first.clone();
        $('.img-container').append(firstClone);
        $('.img-container').animate({ "left": "-=110px" }, "slow", function() {
            first.remove();
            $('.img-container').css("left", "0");
        });
    }
});
$('#next').click(function () {
    if(!$('.img-container').is(':animated')) {
        var last = $('.img-container img:last-child');
        var lastClone = last.clone();
        $('.img-container').css("left", "-110px");
        $('.img-container').prepend(lastClone);
        $('.img-container').animate({ "left": "0" }, "slow", function() {
            last.remove();
        });
    }
});
});
```

Note the 'if not animated' check at the beginning of each function.  This prevents the user from running the functions again before the animation has completed (which would cause weird errors).

Here is a modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fJqKV/17/